# Is there an open source rhythm / music game framework?

Tags: music, prototyping

I'm trying to build a very simple rhythm game (as a one-off art installation, not a commercial project) demonstrating a novel controller, but I've got an extremely short timeframe to do it in. Are there any open-source rhythm games or frameworks out there that I could use instead of writing such a game from scratch?

I could probably bang the code together in PyGame or Processing over a few days, but any time I can save on programming can be spent instead on the physical build, which would make the overall installation better.  The requirements for the game itself are super simple -- I just need to scroll notes across the screen, register points based on how well the player matches them, and play a song (ducking one of the channels when a note is missed).

The custom controller is Arduino-based, sending its data as bytes over a serial port, so I don't need any fancy DirectX support. Just something that can run with <60ms latency.

Answer (score 4):

It probably would be more effort to strip them down, but if you're curious both [StepMania](http://sourceforge.net/projects/stepmania/) and [Frets on Fire](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fretsonfire/) are open source.

Answer (score 0):

Demo programming opensource, also links to some other demo/game engines : http://elsewhere.stc.cx/demoprogramming/

Comment: Which one is a music framework? is it possible to view the source without downloading the files?